# Getting dataframe column in variable, how to?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql

Environment: Spark 1.6  ,Scala

I am trying to get one datetime Field from dataframe to compare in SparkSQL.

```
val las_max_date_from_hive= hivecontext.sql("select min(SampleTime) max_SampleTime from mytable")

DF2 = hivecontext.sql ("select * from table2 where sampleDate >" + las_max_date_from_hive) // error here as  las_max_date_from_hive is a DF
```

How can I get datetime out of dataframe and use in SQL?

Thanks
Hossain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple - `sql` return DataFrame, but you are sure that it has only one element, so you can do:

```
val last_max_date_from_hive = hivecontext.sql("select min(SampleTime) max_SampleTime from mytable")

val firstRow = last_max_date_from_hive.map {
    // only value is important
    case Row (value) => value.asInstanceOf[java.sql.Timestamp]; // cast to Date
}.first()

// we use SimpleDateFormat to parse to proper string format
val df2 = sqlContext.sql ("select * from mytable where SampleTime > cast('" 
    + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(firstRow) 
    + "' as date)");
```

If you don't want to parse Timestamp object, then you can use `from_unixtime` function and `getTime()`:

```
val firstRow = las_max_date_from_hive.map {
    case Row (value) => value.asInstanceOf[java.sql.Timestamp].getTime() / 1000
}.first();

val df2 = sqlContext.sql ("select * from mytable where cast(SampleTime as timestamp) > from_unixtime(" + firstRow + ")")
```

Comment: Thanks, Gaweda for your response. I tried your code and got error  `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.sql.Date`

Comment: @Hossain That's because my test data has `Date` column, you has `Timestamp` - I've updated answer

Comment: @Hossain One more example without parsing Timestamp. Be aware, that you can use `java.util.Date` as it is parent class of Timestamp and sql.Date

Comment: @Gaweda, thanks a lot. your code is working exactly the way I need. Appreciating your support.